# Does knowing a graph has a Hamiltonian Cycle make it easier to find the cycle?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Given a simple and connected graph $G=(V, E)$. I know it's NP-Complete to determine if $G$ has a Hamiltonian Cycle (HC). But if we know $G$ indeed contains an HC, can we find the cycle in poly-time?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://xkcd.com/230/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No (or rather: no, unless P=NP).

If it were so, then there would be a concrete polynomial $p$ that bounded the running time of such an algorithm. Therefore you would be able to detect *whether* a graph has a Hamiltonian cycle by *lying to the algorithm*: Claim that the graph has a Hamiltonian cycle, run it for $p(n)$ steps, and then check whether by then it has printed a correct cycle or not.